# How to show first slide on tab load on a multi tab page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have four tabs and the first tab has a slide show.
I am able to trigger the first tab on page load but for some reason the first slide of the slideshow inside the first tab shows a blank image. I can't figure out from where I can invoke the showSldies() function to load the first image in the slideshow as soon as the tab loads. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the main index page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BHU MCA Portal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="material.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"> 
       </script>
        <script>
                var slideIndex = 1;
                showSlides(slideIndex);

                function plusSlides(n) {
                showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                }

                function currentSlide(n) {
                showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                }

                function showSlides(n) {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                slides[i].style.display = "none";  
                }
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
        $('#main').load('home.php #main');
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function () {
                $('#main').load(this.id+'.php #main');
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active", "");
                this.className += "active";
                }
            }
        }); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
        </script>
    </head>
    <div>
        <center><img src="img/logo_main.png" height="20%" width="30%"></center>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="home" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="portal">Attendance Portal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="about" onclick="openLink(event, 'Right')">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

        <div style="display:flex;">
        <div id="main" style="flex-grow:1;"></div>
        <div style="line-height: 25px; font-style: italic;">
            <img src="img/mmm.jpg" style="display: inline-block;" >
            <p>"Religion of students is acquisition of knowledge"</p>
            <p align="right">~ Mahamana Pt Madan Mohan Malaviya</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

This is home.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div id="main" class="form w3-animate-top">
<div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="images\15.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Administration Building</div>
        </div>

        ...<more slides here>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
   <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
<br>
</div>
</html>
```

Pastebin link to complete code :
https://pastebin.com/Qm0XibKB
https://pastebin.com/mGetfw8K

UPDATE:

This code works now:
https://pastebin.com/T9FG8VhE

Comment: getElementsByClassName is not the same as element.classList.contains(). You are looking for "mySlides" when you only have "mySlidesfade"

Comment: mySlides and fade are different classes. And can you elaborate the first part of your comment

Comment: Yes, I see that. It was a typo. I meant, "mySlides fade". getElementsByClassName("whatever") will look for any elements whose class is only "whatever". Not, just if it has that class.

Comment: Tried removing the fade style from each of the slides. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I wasn't providing an answer, I was making a comment on the code. Refer to the answers for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `showSlides(slideIndex);` before the HTML and home.php have loaded. I would try creating a [Callback Function for the .load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function) and moving this line into that function:

**First:** Remove the `showSlides(slideIndex);` from the top of the script

```
...
var slideIndex = 1;
//remove from here
//showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
...
```

**Second:** Create the Callback Function for the .load() method and insert `showSlides(slideIndex);` into that function

```
...
$(document).ready(function() { /// Wait till page is loaded
    $('#main').load('home.php #main', function() { //begin Callback Function
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function () {
                $('#main').load(this.id+'.php #main');
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace("active", "");
                this.className += "active";
            }
        }
        showSlides(slideIndex); //insert here
    }); //end Callback Function

}); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
...
```

Comment: I am working on my local machine. Here is the entire code : 
https://pastebin.com/vXETx2zn
https://pastebin.com/k8vuQu5J

Comment: And you are sure you removed `showSlides(slideIndex);` after `var slideIndex = 1;` and inserted it instead as the last line of your `$(document).ready(function() {}` block? Could you post your full updated index page code to pastebin.com?

Comment: Yes I did. Still the same issue. Here's the updated code :
https://pastebin.com/CDQVL132

Comment: I have updated my solution. Give that code a try and let me know.

Comment: Got it. I just moved the slideIndex initialization to the wrong palce. It is working now. But now I am facing issue with navigation :

https://pastebin.com/MiRxyuec

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working, good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Now the first slide is loading fine but when I reload the tab after moving to a diffrent tab then again the same issue. And also the navigation buttons of the slides are not working. Just a little more help :/

Comment: Navigation is fixed now :https://pastebin.com/57LGQvQK

But can the showSldies method be called every time the tab loads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183307/discussion-between-justin-t-and-nishant-agarwal).